# Compare date and delete if it's older than today

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

How would I delete a date if it's older than "today." How do I append all the items not just the date? I hope I'm at least on the right track.

```
    var future =  [
     {
       "month":"march",
       "day":1,
       "year":2014,
       "movie":"thor"
       },
     {
       "month":"may",
       "day":29,
       "year":2020,
       "movie":"superman"
       },
     {
       "month":"may",
       "day":29,
       "year":2020,
       "movie":"batman"
       }
    ];

   var afterToday = [];

   future.forEach(function(item){
       var today = new Date();
       var zzz =  new Date(item.day + " " + item.month + " " + item.year);
       if(zzz > today)
       {
         afterToday[length] = zzz;
           $('body').append(afterToday);
       }
```

Comment: The arguments to `Date` constructor are supposed to be numbers here.

Comment: @Jack I don't think so. Date constructor accepts the date string.  http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp

Comment: I solved my problem with [Date JS](http://www.datejs.com/)

Answer (score 2):

For modern browsers try

```
var future = [{
    "month": "march",
    "day": 1,
    "year": 2014
}, {
    "month": "may",
    "day": 29,
    "year": 2020
}, {
    "month": "may",
    "day": 16,
    "year": 2014
}];

var array = ['jan', 'feb', 'march', 'april', 'may'];
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0);
today.setMinutes(0);
today.setSeconds(0);
today = today.setMilliseconds(0);
future = future.filter(function (value) {
    return new Date(value.year, array.indexOf(value.month), value.day) >= today;
})

console.log(future)
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AhqG7/)

---

Cross browser using jQuery

```
future = $.grep(future, function(value){
    return new Date(value.year, $.inArray(array, value.month), value.day) > today;
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/AhqG7/3/)

Comment: This implementation is great. However, if by "older than today" the user means older than midnight last night. Then today has to be adjusted thus, `today = new Date();
today.setHours(0);
today.setMinutes(0);
today.setSeconds(0);
today = today.setMilliseconds(0);` and the rest of the code accordingly. Otherwise this is a perfect implementation of "older than now."

Answer (score 0):

you'll need to determine a 0-based value for month (0-11) for the date, then you can [splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) the past date from the array.

<kbd>[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jxL6K/)</kbd>

```
var future = [{
    "month": "march",
        "day": 1,
        "year": 2014
}, {
    "month": "may",
        "day": 29,
        "year": 2020
}],
    now = new Date(),
    months = [ 'january', 'february', 'march', 'april', 'may', 'june', 'july', 'august', 'september', 'october', 'november', 'december' ],
    getMonth = function(monthString) {
        return months.indexOf(monthString);
    }

for (var i in future) {
    var date = new Date(future[i].year, getMonth(future[i].month), future[i].day),
        isPast = date < now;

    if (isPast) {
        future.splice(i, 1);
    }
}

console.log(future);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can turn each of your dates into a string that's easily parsed by Date.parse.

```
var today = new Date();
today.setHours(0,0,0,0);

future = future.filter(function(date) {
    var parsableDate = date.month + ' ' + date.day + ', ' + date.year;
    return Date.parse(parsableDate) > today;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Fist of all, you don't need to create a month array as js Date supports the format like "01 march 2014".
And I would suggest you add the future date to another array.

```
 var future =  [
     {
       "month":"march",
       "day":1,
       "year":2014
       },
     {
       "month":"may",
       "day":29,
       "year":2020
       }
    ];

   var afterToday = [];

   future.forEach(function(item){
       var today = new Date();
       var zzz =  new Date(item.day + " " + item.month + " " + item.year);
       if(zzz > today)
       {
         afterToday[length] = zzz;
       }
    });
```